# Call a Sub-scene in React Native Router Flux without calling an Initial sub-scene

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I have two sub scene in my `react-native-router-flux` Router like

```
<Router>
  <Scene key="root" ... >
    <Scene key="login" ... />
    <Scene key="parent" component={drawer}>
      <Scene key="page1" ... />
      <Scene key="page2" ... />
    </Scene>
  </Scene>
</Router>
```

Now, I'm in login scene. If I want to call `page2`, I'm using the following snippet.

```
Actions.parent()
Actions.page2()
```

It is working. But, Before rendering the `page2` It is executing the `page1` also, Since it is the initial element. How to open `page2` without executing the `page1`?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
import { Actions, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';

<Button onPress={() => {
    Actions.parent({type:ActionConst.RESET});
    Actions.page2();
}}>
```